# How to trigger jit debugger under windows while in wndproc message handler?

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I wrote a ASSERT macro like following code:

```
do{
    if (true) { 
        int ret = _DbgCheckMsg(__WSHORT_FILE__, __LINE__, L"haha", L"haha", (const wchar_t*)nullptr);
        if (ret == 1) {
            TRACEF("called int 3");
            __asm int 3;
            TRACEF("after called int 3");
        } else if (ret == -1) 
            _DbgAbort();
    }
} while (0);
```

It works well when run with F5 in visual studio, or without F5 but not in wndproc handler, but if run without F5 and in wndproc message handler, the wndproc just swallow the breakpoint exception siliently, JUST AS WHAT IT DOES TO the c standard assert function.

But I need to trigger the jit dialog while in the wndproc message handler without a debugger attached first. How could I do it?

I haved tried to warp the wndproc in a SEH, but it did not help, because it will break into the exception handler rather than break at the message handler code.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWrapper(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    __try {
        return WndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    } __except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH) {
        TRACEF("exception caught");
        //LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS pep = GetExceptionInformation();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @EdwardClements: DebugBreak() does not help, because it is actually __asm int 3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from [access violation in WM_PAINT not caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487950/access-violation-in-wm-paint-not-caught)

Actually only some wm messages is caught by SEH, for example WM_LBUTTONDOWN is not caught by SEH. Remove all SEH handler before call WndProc then you could use __asm int 3 or __debugbreak() to break the application.

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcWrapper(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        // get thread information block
        NT_TIB* tib;
        __asm {
            mov EAX, FS:[18h]
            mov [tib], EAX
        }
        // old exception handler list
        _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD* old_exception_handler = tib->ExceptionList;
        // remove all exception handler with exception of the default handler
        while( tib->ExceptionList->Next != (_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD*)-1 ) {
            tib->ExceptionList = tib->ExceptionList->Next;
        }

        LRESULT result = WndProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );

        // restore old exception handler
        tib->ExceptionList = old_exception_handler;

        return result;
    }
```