# Why program will not crash and could still execute After Access Violation?

Tags: c++, winapi, seh

I am coding a C++ win32 app and encounter a weird appearance which is that access violation instruction will not always cause app crashed, It depends  where the instruction inserted! Here is the case I encountered : I have used a third party library, and If I put *(int *0)=0; in one special overload function of that library, The program will not crash and some instruction will be skipped which result that the program run in a abnormal status.  code like the below:

```
void CMainWnd::InitWindow(){
    //other constructions 
    (*(int *)0) = 0;//access violation
   //other construction which is under *(int *0)=0; in InitWindow scope will not be executed.
   //.....
}
```

I guess the library have used some SEH Technology, so search through the library codebase and not found any relative API used.

SO, WHAT HAPPENED???

----- split line ----------

Thanks everyone's response, after Daniel Sęk`s prompt. I add more detail to here.   Here is crash function call stack.

```
duidemo_d.exe!crash() Line 73   C++
duidemo_d.exe!CMainWnd::InitWindow() Line 89    C++
DuiLib_d.dll!DuiLib::WindowImplBase::OnCreate(unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, int & bHandled) Line 313 C++
DuiLib_d.dll!DuiLib::WindowImplBase::HandleMessage(unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 359    C++
DuiLib_d.dll!DuiLib::CWindowWnd::__WndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 436 C++
```

here is how **DuiLib_d.dll!DuiLib::CWindowWnd::__WndProc** is invoked.Registers a window class which has **WNDCLASS::lpfnWndProc=CWindowWnd::__WndProc**  for subsequent use in calls to the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function.

------split line-----

The reason for why I do this test is that I want to catch every unexpected thing happens in my program and dump it ,debug it ,figure out how it happened and solve it, finally reduce one bug. It seems that my catch method does not work well if exception happened in wndproc whatsoever [exceotion code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679356(v=vs.85).aspx) is.   Here is the method how I create dump file.**SetUnhandledExceptionFilter** is called after **WinMain**.

```
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER)CallBackCrashHandler);
//dump
LONG CallBackCrashHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pException)
{
//write dump
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(gBugReport->m_dumpFilePath.data(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION l_eInfo;
l_eInfo.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
l_eInfo.ExceptionPointers = pException;
l_eInfo.ClientPointers = FALSE;

MiniDumpWriteDump(
    GetCurrentProcess(),
    GetCurrentProcessId(),
    hFile,
    MiniDumpNormal,
    pException ? &l_eInfo : NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);
return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}
```

Comment: It has a few difference. It always will not cause app crash when access violation instruction in CMainWnd::InitWindow other than  other scope

Comment: @NickyC How to remove The Title：This question may already have an answer here？ It has a few difference. I said that It has just happened in CMainWnd::InitWindow, So It is not a undefined behaviour.

Comment: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @No.6 It is undefined behavior. Do you know some place that defines this behavior and says that code must crash? Because I don't.

Comment: Try `RaiseException` instead, possibly with the `EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE` flag.

Comment: Someone closed question so I paste it here.

1. You have somewhere SEH handler which just ignores exception.
2. You have active translation of SEH to C++ exceptions and these exceptions are eaten by `catch (...)`.
**3. You are developing 32 bit application on 64 bit Windows system and exception is thrown in some callback (for example `WindowProc`). 32 bit application can't safely unwind stack when called from 64 bit kernel and exceptions are unfortunately swallowed.** Investigate if your case is my case #3.

Comment: @DanielSęk, Thanks, After I test， My problem belongs to your case #3,

Comment: @No.6 I would recommend [WindowProc calback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573(VS.85).aspx) **Remarks section** and [Crashing correctly](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/w4z6y/crashing_correctly_is_surprisingly_difficult_on/)

Comment: @DanielSęk, I add more detail to there, the network is so poor, so my response is so slowly.

Comment: To prevent swallowing, wrap code in `WindowProc` with SEH `__try {} __except () {}`. [Structured Exception Handling C/C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx)

Comment: See also [Mixing SEH and C++ Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/01/11/mixing-seh-and-c-exceptions/) and [Structured Exception Handling SEH and C++ exception handling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zhanli/2010/06/25/structured-exception-handling-seh-and-c-exception-handling/)

Comment: Perfect links. I will read up every article, thanks.

Comment: The unhandled exception filter only runs, in case the exception is indeed, well, unhandled. As explained in a comment above, the system does handle exceptions under certain circumstances. Besides, your `MiniDumpWriteDump` implementation is a guaranteed dead lock. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41433641/1889329) for details. In short: `MiniDumpWriteDump` must be called from a different process, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx).

Comment: This might be a better duplicate than the selected one: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/1487950/886887 see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/11376795/886887

Comment: I used method from your link@DanielSęk, It works good. But after do more test, I draw a conclusion whether SetUnhandledExceptionFilter will work well is also relevant to WM_MESSAGE type under `WindowProc`.  Because I found that **CallBackCrashHandler** can not  catch exception under **WM_CREATE** Message  in  `WindowProc` , can catch exception  under **WM_LBUTTONUP**.Message  in  `WindowProc`.

Comment: Thank @Harry Johnston, I get a lot useful info from your link.